# 3-level hierarchical model and ferquentist approach

Tags: model, likelihood, frequentist, extreme-value

Could I use maximum likelihood method or any other frequenist method to estimate parameters for 3-level hierarchical model?
Is there any references help me in this case?
Thank you

Comment: What's the problem? You mean in theory? Or in practice? Did you try anything?

Comment: I mean in practice. Yes I tried to use the maximum likelihood to estimate the parameters in the first level, then I use these estimates as data and I use it  to estimate parameters in second level ( I use rma function from metafor package in r), then I consider estimates  from second level as data and I use it to estimate parameters in third level also by using rma function.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit a mixed model with three levels, or more, with `lme4`. There's not a lot mentioned in their vignette. You need the `:` operator. Here is a link to a tutorial: http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to look at this tutorial and I hope that will help me.